# Flutter json_rpc_2 implementation

Tags: dart, flutter, json-rpc

Did anyone successfully implemented WebSocket using json_rpc_2 package?https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_rpc_2

I try to present live data, e.g. a ticker, from this API: https://api.hitbtc.com/

Comment: Websocket?  Websockets are awesome for two way communications, when you control both server and client. But that is not the case here. Instead, why not use using HTTP protocol for this data source?  [link1](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/)   [link2](https://medium.com/@mohamedraja_77/create-your-first-api-call-in-flutter-a04d023ebd50) .  update... wow, that api offers socket connections.  Do you really need that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I managed to solve the problem. Here's the code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:json_rpc_2/json_rpc_2.dart' as json_rpc;
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

class SymbolDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final String symbolId;

  SymbolDetails({this.symbolId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _api = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('wss://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/ws');
    var client = json_rpc.Client(_api.cast());
    client.sendNotification(
      'subscribeTicker',
      {'symbol': '$symbolId'},
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('$symbolId details'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _api.stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Please check your internet connection'),
            );
          } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          String _snapshotData = snapshot.data;
          Map _response = json.decode(_snapshotData);
          return ListView(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Ask price:'),
                trailing: Text(
                  '${_response['params']['ask']}',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Bid price:'),
                trailing: Text(
                  '${_response['params']['bid']}',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a more fleshed-out example that runs on MongoDB. It is also null-safe. Here is the API I came up with:

```
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as shelf_io;
import 'package:shelf_web_socket/shelf_web_socket.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart' as mongo;

void main() async {
  final handler = webSocketHandler((WebSocketChannel socket){
    final server = Server(socket.cast<String>());
    server.registerMethod('hello', () async{
      mongo.Db db = mongo.Db('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/obj1');
      await db.open();
      var list = await db.collection('Person').find(null).toList();
  //    await db.close();
      return list;
    });
    server.listen();
  });
  final server = await shelf_io.serve(handler, '127.0.0.1', 4042);
  print('Serving at ws://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
}
```

Here is the Flutter client:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:json_rpc_2/json_rpc_2.dart' as json_rpc;
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var api = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('ws://127.0.0.1:4042'));
    var client = json_rpc.Client(api.cast());
    client.sendRequest(
'hello',

    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: api.stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
            return  const Center(
              child: Text('Please check your internet connection'),
            );
          } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return  const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          String snapshotData = snapshot.data;
          Map<String,dynamic> raw = json.decode(snapshotData);List items = raw['result'];
          return  ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('${items[index]["first_name"].toString()} ${items[index]["last_name"].toString()}'),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When all goes well, the end result is a formatted list of names.